# Help with list validation please

Tags: list, validation

I'm trying to do a validation in one of our list. Basically, I have a Drop Down box with 5 choices (let's say `choice1` to `choice5`).

If `choice2` OR `choice3` is choosen, I'd like to have a mandatory field (single line of text). I can't come up with the correct syntax to make it work. Here's something not working.

```
=IF(OR([coloumn1]="choice2";[coloumn1]="choice3");AND([coloumn2]<>"";TRUE;FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
=IF(or(c1="choice2",c2="choice3"),isblank(c2),true)
```

The logic is

```
if c1 = choice2 or c2 = choice3
      check if c2 is blank (if blank return false, else return true)
else
      return true
```

**Update**

```
=IF(OR([column2]="pineapple",[column2]="apple"),IF(ISBLANK([simplelineoftext]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! I've tried it and can't make it work. Here's what I've tried: =IF(OR([column1]="choice2";[column1]="choice3");ISBLANK([simplelineoftext1],TRUE)) This is getting me a syntax error.

Comment: You did it wrong. it should be `=IF(or([column1]="choice2";[column2]="choice3");isblank([simplelineoftext1]);true)`

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the syntax error but the validation doesn't work still: =IF(OR([column1]="choice2";[column1]="choice3");ISBLANK([simplelineoftext1]);TRUE)

Comment: I just saw your reply, thanks for your time! I'm not sure I understand the [column2] in your formula. The drop down box is 5 choices in the same column. Let's say; "Which fruit you like the most" 1. strawberry, 2. pineapple, 3. apple. If choice 2 or 3 is choosen, make the simplelineoftext mandatory. Hopefully it's a bit more clear hehe

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the same for 2 choices using below Formula, hope including another choice (IF condition) works for you.

```
=IF([Choice1]="xx",IF([column]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```